# DevExpress XtraGrids horizontal scroll is slow. How to speed it up?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have 11 visible grids that are synchronized - LeftCoords of children ones is set when LeftCoord of parent one changes. Those grids have around 50 columns, but it could possibly by more. When all grids are visible horizontal scrolling becomes very slow. Those grid have some customized behaviors.

Is there some grid functionality that makes horizontal scroll slower, or is it normal speed? Are there any known ways of making it faster?

I am using version 13.2.

Thanks,
Peter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of columns in grid. I suggest you that you limit the number of columns to show by hiding unnecessary ones. If an end-user needs a particular column, he/she will be able to make it visible from the Column Chooser.

Handling any custom draw events, applying format conditions, or using unbound columns will decrease performance.

**Source:** [Horizontal scrolling is very slow when there are large number of columns in the grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q97627)

> Please increase the `GridView.HorzScrollStep` property and set the
>   `GridView.ScrollStyle` property to none to disable live scrolling.
>   Additionally, there is a request on providing the per-column scrolling
>   in the [XtraGrid at Horizontal scrolling by a column at a time (as in
>   MS Excel](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S18225.aspx))

References:
[Scrolling speed both Horizontal an vertical](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ50859)